# greediness in R regular expressions with lookahead

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to use lookahead to find strings that match a certain subexpression at the beginning of a phrase but not match a certain subexpression aftewards.

For example, I want this

```
temp <- c("hello_i_am_in_the_park", "hey, park your car here")
grep("h.*park.*(?!here)", temp, perl=T,value=T)
```

to return:

```
[1] "hello_i_am_in_the_park"
```

But instead I get:

```
[1] "hello_i_am_in_the_park"  "hey, park your car here"
```

I assume this is something to do with the non greediness of .* but can't seem to figure out how to modify the expression to make it more greedy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `.*` into the lookahead:

```
h.*park(?!.*here)
          ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC2dP8/1)

This regex will work this way:

- `h` - matches the first `h` (prepend with `^` to match at the start of the string)
- `.*` - will match 0+ characters other than newline (since this is a PCRE regex, `.` does not match a newline by default)
- `park` - matches a literal `park`
- `(?!.*here)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 0+ characters other than a newline followed with the `here` substring.

If your text has newlines, and the word `here` may be located on another line below the `park`, you need to add an inline modifier `(?s)`:

```
"(?s)h.*park(?!.*here)"
```

An alternative regex would be to perform the check immediately at the beginning of a string:

```
^(?!.*here)h.*park
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aC2dP8/2). This way, we quickly check for the banned substring, and if it is there, no `h`, no `.*` and no `park` are searched for.

And last but not least: if you need to match *whole words* only, do not forget to add `\b` word boundaries:

```
"^(?!.*\\bhere\\b)h.*\\bpark\\b"
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor your comprehensive answer